# Java Design: Decouple JNI Library

Tags: java, soap, java-native-interface

I have two C libraries of the same third-party device. The difference is one (say Library A) having more functions than the other (say Library B). I have two big platforms using the device. Platform A uses Library A while Platform B uses Library B.

In order to support more platforms and systems, I am thinking if I should create a Web Service (e.g. SOAP) of the device function calls. If so, any change of the libraries which does not change the existing function interfaces does not require re-compilation on the big platforms. In addition, if a new platform is introduced, the library and the web service can be re-used. The design looks like:

Platform <-- SOAP --> Lightweight Web Server <-- JNI --> Device Library

Is it a good design? Any disadvantage?

In addition, since there are two libraries, could I create a single Java class supporting both libraries? If yes, how could I handle unimplemented methods?

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like more of a dependency management issue that could be solved with a declarative dependency management tool.

Have you thought about storing your DLLs as separate artifacts in a nexus-like server dependency tool?  That way you could prepare different deployment profiles with a maven-like tool with the proper DLL library artifact (assuming there are no code changes in the common java code base).

This way everything would be solved at deploy time and you would need no additional webservices to look for your device library at run time (this leads to other problems, like the availability of your service, or where to publish it to start with)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your approach sounds Platform A->Business Class A->JNI Class A->Library A; Platform B->Business Class B->JNI Class B->Library B. Class A and B repeat and it violates code reuse. In addition, the approach could not handle the third party program because it most likely integrates other systems by standard way such as Web Services rather than directly calling the C library. Our situation is that the number of machines is very large. Your critics on webservices is valid. To handle it, the service should be installed into the same machine and start at bootup.